# Отладчик bat файлов с пользовательским интерфейсом.

Tags: bat

Кто-нибудь видел такое?

Comment: Вроде такого и не существует

Comment: Гугл сразу же вываливает: https://jpsoft.com/ и http://batchdebugger.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть такая среда - **Running Steps CMD File IDE**.

Правда, если скрипт слишком сложен для отладки с помощью печати в логи, разумно посмотреть в сторону PowerShell: там есть отладка сценариев.